# Limit output results of an array

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, limit

I wanna limit the result to 10 elements (10 words). This is the code I got:

```
function ls_bp_hashtags_cloud() {
    $args = array () ;
    if ( bp_is_activity_component() ) {
        $toHead = __( 'Popular Hashtags across network' , 'bp-hashtags' ) ;
    }
    if ( bp_is_user_activity() ) {
        $toHead = __( 'Hashtags by user' , 'bp-hashtags' ) ;
        $args[ 'user_id' ] = bp_displayed_user_id() ;
    }
    if ( bp_is_group_activity() || bp_is_group_home() ) {
        $toHead = __( 'Hashtags in group' , 'bp-hashtags' ) ;
        $args[ 'if_activity_item_id' ] = bp_get_current_group_id() ;
    }
    echo '<div align="right"><h5>' . $toHead . '</h5>' ;
    echo ls_bp_hashtags_generate_cloud( $args ) ;
    echo '</div>' ;
}
```

And thisone below is the ls_bp_hashtags_generate_cloud() function:

```
 function ls_bp_hashtags_generate_cloud( $args = array() ) {
    $hashtags = ls_bp_hashtags_get_hashtags( $args );
    $defaults = array(
    'smallest' => 10, 'largest' => 10, 'unit' => 'pt', 'number' => 0,
    'format' => 'flat', 'separator' => ",\n\n", 'orderby' => 'count', 'order' => 'DESC',
    'topic_count_text_callback' => 'default_topic_count_text',
    'topic_count_scale_callback' => 'default_topic_count_scale', 'filter' => 1
);
    $args = wp_parse_args( $args, $defaults );
    extract( $args );
    $tag_cloud = wp_generate_tag_cloud( $hashtags, $args );
    $tag_cloud = '<div class="hashtags">' . $tag_cloud . '</div>';

    return $tag_cloud;
}
```

I got this other one too, not sure if it's needed:

```
function ls_bp_hashtags_get_hashtags( $args = array() ) {
    global $wpdb;
    $bp = buddypress();
    $link = $bp->root_domain . "/" . $bp->activity->slug . "/" . BP_ACTIVITY_HASHTAGS_SLUG . "/";
    bp_hashtags_set_constants();

    $data = maybe_unserialize( get_site_option( 'ls_bp_hashtags' ) );

    if ( $data['style']['show_hashsymbol'] == '1' ) {
    $hashtag_name = ' CONCAT( "#", hashtag_name)';
    } else {
    $hashtag_name = 'hashtag_name ';
    }


    $toWhere = ls_bp_hashtags_generate_query_limitations( $args );

    $results = $wpdb->get_results( 'SELECT COUNT(hashtag_name) as count, '
    . $hashtag_name . ' as name, '
    . 'CONCAT("' . $link . '", hashtag_slug) as link
    FROM ' . BP_HASHTAGS_TABLE . ' WHERE 1=1 ' . $toWhere . ' GROUP BY hashtag_name' );

    return $results;
}
```

The first snippet I pasted here is in one file while the last 2 snippets are in another file.
I think I have to modify the function ls_bp_hashtags_generate_cloud(), the point is I don't know how to do that. I tried with array_slice() and with $sql = "SELECT * FROM bp_activity LIMIT 10"; I checked mysql database, my ashtags are located in bp_ashtags table, but when I open this table I see each hashtag is referred to be in bp_activity table.
This function gives me the ashtags cloud of my buddypress activity stream page, so it gives me all the ahstags present in the database, instead I wanna limit the result to just 10 #ashtags (it's a wordpress website). That said I'm really a novice so please if you can help me giving me the whole snippet to add and where to put it, I know almost nothing about php coding. If you need to know other things about this code, just tell me; thisone is an extract so I don't know if I'm missing something for the solution. Thank you in advance

Comment: Seems you have to modify the function ls_bp_hastags_generate_cloud() to limit the output since there are no other places where multipe words are output.

Comment: Yes, I have to modify the function ls_bp_hashtags_generate_cloud(), the point is I don't know how to do that. I tried with array_slice() and with $sql = "SELECT * FROM bp_activity LIMIT 10";

Comment: Show us the function and we can help you. We need to know what the function does (data structure,loops,...).

Comment: The posted function is ls_bp_hashtags_cloud(). It calls ls_bp_hashtags_generate_cloud(). If you can edit ls_bp_hashtags_generate_cloud(), we need to see that.

Comment: Hm. Not sure how to rephrase this. You need to find the definition of the function ls_bp_hashtags_generate_cloud(). Note the "generate" in the middle of the name. You've posted the function ls_bp_hashtags_cloud() -- no "generate"... Can you please find and post the contents of the function with generate in it... "ls_bp_hashtags_generate_cloud"

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I have to modify the function ls_bp_hashtags_generate_cloud(), the point is I don't know how to do that. I tried with array_slice() and with $sql = "SELECT * FROM bp_activity LIMIT 10";  I checked mysql database, my ashtags are located in bp_ashtags table, but when I open this table I see each hashtag is referred to be in bp_activity table. This function gives me the ashtags cloud of my buddypress activity stream page, so it gives me all the ahstags present in the database, instead I wanna limit the result to just 10 #ashtags (it's a wordpress website). That said I'm really a novice so please if you can help me giving me the whole snippet to add and where to put it.

Comment: You should be able to edit your question directly - not reply in answers.